# CodeIgniter not working in sub-directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.1.1 .

The problem is when i browse sub-directory(http://www.wap.com/demosite) where CodeIgniter installed, it always redirect to main domain and i think the problem is in `.htaccess`.

For example :

Domain : http://www.wap.com

Main site directory `public_html/`

And `.htaccess` file in main-directory `public_html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit

ErrorDocument 500 /errors/404
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/404
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/404
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://wap.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js)$ - [F,NC]
```

CodeIgniter installation directory

```
public_html/demosite/
```

And `.htaccess` file in sub-directory `public_html/demosite/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the move is a new addition?

Need to make sure that in application/config/config.php that your base_url is set to `http://www.wap.com/demosite` not to `http://www.wap.com`

This is often missed and causes these kinds of redirects

Your codeigniter htaccess should also be set to `RewriteBase /demosite/`